# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}pe^{-tp^2} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to show the following integral is equal to zero

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}pe^{-tp^2}$$

If I let $u = tp^2$, I get

$dp = \frac{1}{2tp}du$

So I have $\frac{1}{2t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u}du$

$\frac{1}{2t}\big[-e^{-u}\big]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$

which diverges. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did not substitute the integration boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Your substititution is not valid on $(-\infty, \infty)$. The function you are substituting with must be bijective (one-to-one) on the interval of substitution.

I suggest you calculate the integral as

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty pe^{-tp^2}dp = \int_{-\infty}^0pe^{-tp^2}dp +\int_{0}^\infty pe^{-tp^2}dp$$

Or, you can avoid integration completely if you notice that the function being integrated is odd.

Comment: Ok thanks. Would it also be ok to say the $p$ is odd, $e^{-tp^2}$ is even, and hence the integrand is odd. Therefore the integral over $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $0$?

Comment: ... we of course assume or know that the integral exists.

Comment: @csss You need to add another word or two about whether the integral even exists, but other than that, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If the improper integral is taken as 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-x}^{x}pe^{-tp^2} d p$$ the integral is zero because you have an odd integrand and therefore
$$\int_{-x}^{x}pe^{-tp^2}d p =0$$

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

Since (with $\;p\;$ the variable, $\;t>0\;$):

$$p=-\frac1{2t}(-2tp)=-\frac1{2t}(-tp^2)'$$

we get that

$$\int pe^{-tp^2}dp=-\frac1{2t}e^{-tp^2}+C$$

and thus we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty pe^{-tp^2}dp=\left.-\frac1{2t}e^{-tp^2}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=0$$

since

$$\lim_{p\to\pm\infty}e^{-tp^2}=0$$